# Fortran 90 - reading format

Tags: format, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to read that string in a formatted file: `"      PARAMETER (NE_M=10,NL_M=12)"`.

I want to replace the `12` by `11`.

I tried to read the sting like this :

```
integer :: i
character(len=30) :: text
10 format(6x,24a,2i) text,i
read(text_data,10) text, i
write(6,100) text, 11
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: What it means "It doesn't work?", such a description is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading and writing you have written will not do what you want.  The input statement you presented for reading is 33 characters wide, and your formatting only accounts for 32 of those characters and your write will not contain the closing `)`.

Consider the following code, if you do not need to capture the `12` in the input.

```
program test

character(len=30) :: text
101 format(a30, i2, ')')
open(unit=10, file='testinput.f')
read(10,101) text 
write(*,101) text, 11

end program
```

and the input (with 6 leading spaces) in file `testinput.f`:

```
      PARAMETER (NE_M=10,NL_M=12)
```

when run, produces the output:

```
% ./test                     
      PARAMETER (NE_M=10,NL_M=11)
```

This code was compiled and tested with GNU gfortran 4.8.2.

Comment: +1. No idea why this was not upvoted yet. By the way as one of the top users of the FORTRAN tag, I thought you'd be delighted to see this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6252/5 on a brand new SE site!

Answer (score 0):

assuming test_data is a unit number of an open file and 100 is a
format statement number.

```
integer :: i
character(len=30) :: text
10 format(6x,a24,i2)
read(text_data,10) text, i
write(6,100) text(:24), i
```

fixing those other issues:

```
integer :: i
character(len=30) :: text
open(unit=20,file='filename')
10 format(6x,a24,i2)
read(20,10) text, i
write(6,10) text(:24), i
```

Comment: Personally I think using `100` in the `write` statement and `10` to label the `format` statement is just going to confuse readers unfamiliar with Fortran.